# Can't get audio to mute using vue audio player

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio

I am struggling to get the audio to mute inside the vue app. I have an array of songs that will play, pause, shuffle etc. but cannot get the mute function working. I have the following in the js:

```
mute()
            {
            if (this.muted) {
                return this.volume = this.previousVolume;
            }

            this.previousVolume = this.volume;
            this.volume = 0;
        },
```

With this computed method:

```
muted() {
        return this.volume / 100 === 0;
}
```

I have tried adding this:

```
mutebtn = document.getElementById ("mutebtn")
              mutebtn.addEventListener ("click", mute());
```

With this in the music player:

```
<div id="mutebtn">
                  <i class="icon ion-ios-volume-high" title="Mute" v-if="volume" @click="mute()"></i>
                  <i class="icon ion-ios-volume-off" title="Unmute" v-if="muted" @click="volume"></i>
              </div>
```

This is my first attempt at making a music player and I'm new to all of this and getting confused with the javascript. Any help would be great!

Comment: `mutebtn.addEventListener ("click", mute())` calls the `mute()` function immediately. To avoid that behaviour you can pass a reference to the function `mutebtn.addEventListener ("click", mute)`. Why do you not simply check the value of `HTMLMediaElement.muted`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that sorry. I am using this template https://codepen.io/parca0007/full/omGjjg and trying to get my head around adding the mute button to the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you already have a reference `this.audioPlayer` to control the mute state of the player.

Therefore your method could look something like this:

```js
methods: {
    mute() {
      this.audioPlayer.muted = !this.audioPlayer.muted
    }
}
```

Please note - this is the way Vue recommends you to add something like click listeners to your HTML (see [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)). You should probably **not** use `addEventListener` for such a task.

I added a simple mute button next to the play button:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLxOyj?editors=1111

Another short hint for your example:
You set `this.audioPlayer` like this:

```js
mounted () {
    this.audioPlayer = this.$el.querySelectorAll("audio")[0];
}
```

vue.js provides a cleaner way to reference elements:

```
<audio src="my.mp3" ref="myAudio"></audio>
```

```js
mounted () {
    this.audioPlayer = this.$refs.myAudio;
}
```